# Last key in a std::map

Tags: c++, iterator, stdmap

I am looking for the highest key value (a defined by the comparison operator) of a std::map.

Is this guaranteed to be

```
map.rbegin()->first
```

?

(I am a bit shaky on reverse iterators, and how much freedom there is in the implementation of std::map)

If not, please advise. I cannot change the data structure.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Yes. Map is a sorted container, the reverse iterator must return the elements in reverse (i.e. decreasing) order of their keys.

[Edit: as Charles Bailey points out in his answer, your code gives the greatest key **if it exists** - i.e. if the map is non-empty]

Answer (score 39):

Yes, but remember to check that `map.rbegin() != map.rend()`.

Comment: They are all equivalent checks.

Comment: ... while .empty() is guaranteed to be O(1). (just to clarify what Andreas said)

Answer (score 19):

You can use following method :-

```
if(!map.empty())
    (--map.end())->first;
```

Comment: This is not guaranteed to work. `std::prev(map.end())->first` is safer.

Comment: @KaiPetzke yes that is why I checked the map first. what else can go wrong here please elaborate. thanks

Comment: The problem is, that the C++ standard does not require, that you can apply the `--` operator to the rvalue `map.end()`. For further explanation, see the notes on https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/prev

Comment: @KaiPetzke That's a good point. Then what's the difference between `std::prev(map.end())->first` and `map.rbegin()->first`? They seem pretty much the same.

Comment: @starriet There is no difference between the two variants you are asking about. Because @birubisht introduced the non-portable `(--map.end())`, I recommended to use the portable `std::prev(map.end())` instead. `map.rbegin()` yields an iterator to exactly the same element.

Answer (score 19):

One more way -

```
std::prev(map.end())->first;
```

Comment: What will this return, if the map is empty?

Answer (score 2):

Map store the key value pairs in sorted order so we can access the last element by :-

```
auto it=m.end();
it--;
int element=it->first;
```