# Detect if iterator is last element of std::map

Tags: c++, dictionary, iterator, std

This is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/289715/last-key-in-a-stdmap) but not a duplicate. I'm trying to iterate through a map and print the values of each element, but with slightly different output on the last element. In that question, they recommend using `map.rbegin().base()`, but it's not working for me.

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

int main()
{
    std::map <char, int> charMap = { {'a', 1}, {'b', 2}, {'c', 3}, {'d', 4} };
    for (auto iter = charMap.begin(); iter != charMap.end(); iter++)
    {
        std::cout << iter->first << ":\t" << iter->second;
        if (iter == charMap.rbegin().base())
            std::cout << "\t//This is the last element.\n";
        else
            std::cout << "\n";
    }
}
```

I'd expect my output to look like this:

```
a:    1
b:    2
c:    3
d:    4    //This is the last element.
```

But instead, I am getting this output:

```
a:    1
b:    2
c:    3
d:    4
```

Now I realize that there is a better way to do this, but I would expect this to work also. Why can't I compare `iter` and `charMap.rbegin().base()`?

Comment: Note that in such situations it's often easy to rewrite the loop body such that the special handling occurs for the first rather than the last element.

Comment: @ChristianHackl Note, that obviously this is not the case here :)

Comment: @BartoszKP: Why not? Start every line but the first with a line break, put the "This is the last element" after the loop.

Comment: @ChristianHackl You're right, however OP does realize that, and question is specifically targeted for the flow as it is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`base()` method returns iterator to an element that follows the element to which a reverse iterator is pointing. This means that `rbegin().base()` is equivalent to `end()`

To accomplish your task, you can do this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

int main()
{
    std::map <char, int> charMap = { {'a', 1}, {'b', 2}, {'c', 3}, {'d', 4} };
    for (auto iter = charMap.begin(); iter != charMap.end(); )
    {
        std::cout << iter->first << ":\t" << iter->second;
        if (++iter == charMap.end())
            std::cout << "\t//This is the last element.\n";
        else
            std::cout << "\n";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 17):

Use [`std::next`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/next) from `<iterator>` as

```
if (std::next(iter) == charMap.end())
    std::cout << "\t//This is the last element.\n";
```

instead.

Comment: Oh, I was using a separate iterator then incrementing that one. Nice to know about std::next();

Comment: Valid from C++11

Comment: It is better than use reverse iterators to check if an element is the last, because of the weird logic of reverse iterators. And it solved my problem for a `std::vector`.

Answer (score 4):

Because `std::reverse_iterator` stores iterator with offset of `1`, so that `charMap.rbegin().base() == charMap.end()`. Chart over [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/reverse_iterator) illustrates this.

You should instead use `std::prev` or `std::next` from `<iterator>`:

```
iter == std::prev(charMap.end())
```

or

```
std::next(iter) == charMap.end()
```

Whichever you find more meaningful.

Answer (score 2):

[`base()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/reverse_iterator/base) doesn't return the same element:

> The base iterator refers to the element that is next (from the `std::reverse_iterator::iterator_type perspective`) to the element the `reverse_iterator` is currently pointing to. That is `&*(rit.base() - 1) == &*rit`.

This works as intended:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

int main()
{
    std::map <char, int> charMap = { {'a', 1}, {'b', 2}, {'c', 3}, {'d', 4} };
    auto last = charMap.rbegin();
    ++last;

    for (auto iter = charMap.begin(); iter != charMap.end(); iter++)
    {
        std::cout << iter->first << ":\t" << iter->second;
        if (iter == last.base())
            std::cout << "\t//This is the last element.\n";
        else
            std::cout << "\n";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually, this is not expect to work as `iter` is indeed different from `charMap.rbegin().base()`.

Your logic is correct, the only problem is that `charMap.rbegin().base()` iterator is equal to `charMap.end()`, but you leave your for statement at the moment `iter` reaches the `charMap.end()` value, so it never got the chance to test it in the if statement inside the for loop.

To make it work you could rewrite the if statement in the following way:

```
if (iter->first == charMap.rbegin()->first)
    std::cout << "\t//This is the last element.\n";
else
    std::cout << "\n";
```

So you will be comparing the map key instead of the iterator itself.

Answer (score 0):

Ugly . . . but . . .

```
    auto iterCpy = iter;
    if (++iterCpy == charMap.end())
        std::cout << "\t//This is the last element.\n";
```

use vsoftco's answer :)

Answer (score 0):

This is working:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

int main()
{
    std::map <char, int> charMap = { {'a', 1}, {'b', 2}, {'c', 3}, {'d', 4} };
    for (auto iter = charMap.begin(); ;)
    {
        std::cout << iter->first << ":\t" << iter->second;          
        if (++iter== charMap.end()){
            std::cout << "\t//This is the last element.\n"; break;
        }
        else
            std::cout << "\n";
    }

}
```